# Jquery will success will not show up in div

Tags: jquery, ajax

The problem I am having is that my jquery script is not returning the success to the div and instead simply reloading the page (which should not be possible with the prevent).  My code is below.  Any help would be awesome as I've spent quite a bit of time trying to get this to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var loader = "<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
    $('#paging_container').pajinate({
    show_first_last: false,
    nav_label_next : '>',
    nav_label_prev : '<'    
    });

var loadUrl2 = "productadminprocess.php";
$(".action_buttons").click(function() {
    $("#rightcolumn").html(loader).load(loadUrl2, {productid: $(this).attr("id")});
  });


$("#thesubbie").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault(); 

       /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var loadUrl3 = "sortitems.php";
        var $form = $( this ),
            input = $form.find( 'input[name="sort_item"]' ).val();
        var myRadio = $('input[name=sorters]');
        var checkedValue =  myRadio.filter(':checked').val();

    $.post(loadUrl3, {radio: checkedValue, sort_item: input},
        function(data){
            var content = $(data);
            $('#thebox').html(content);

    });
  });
```

});

Here is the PHP Script that is returning data (a sort essentially)

```
function secure($x) { 


  $x = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
   $x = stripslashes($x);
   return $x; 

} 

$sorters = secure($_GET['sorters']);
$sort_item = secure($_GET['sort_item']);

//Start main query
$products = "SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE name_family = '$sort_item'";
//echo $products;
$list = mysql_query($products);
//echo $list;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($list))  {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['product_name'];
?>

    <div class="products"><img src="images/Product_thumbail.png" width="200" height="220" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"><div class="action_buttons" id="<?php echo $id;  ?>">Update</div></div>
<?php       
    } // end while

?>
```

Comment: Your success function doesn't make much sense. `data` unless you are returning a jquery selector should not be wrapped as a jquery object. How are your returning your data from your PHP script?

Comment: Does the form still submit if you comment out the post command?

Comment: I return a sort code based on input from the form.  The php code is through an external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the $.post block:

```
$.post(
    loadUrl3,
    { radio: checkedValue, sort_item: input },
    function(data) {
        $('#thebox').html(data);
    }
);
```

Also, check your JS Error Log for any errors.

**EDIT:** Try adding `return false;` at the end of the $("#thesubbie").submit() block.

Comment: I attempted the change and although the parameters are posting, it doesn't seem to be connecting to the page nor returning any results from it.  The entire page just reloads.

Comment: i simply gave up on it.  I could not get it to work and there wasn't as much response to it here so I gave up.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution.  It was something as simple as the placement of a quotation mark in the form id which caused the page reload and failure of the entire script.  Thanks.